# Does a solution exist for transferring large files across a network that is faster, yet just as secure as scp?

Tags: file-encryption, file-upload

I'm posting this here rather than unix/linux, because the primary deal breaker here would be a deteriorated security layer.

I'm wondering if there are (*noticeably*) faster solutions available for transferring large amounts of data between hosts, when compared to `scp`? I don't want to compromise the security aspects of `scp` though, so the answer here might just be '*tough luck*', which is fine.

I do hope there exists some service though that allows for full (or at least, nearly full) pipe saturation when transferring data. Perhaps a plausible solution would be to `tar` the files into an encrypted tar before transferring? Then we could be free to transfer using whichever utility we desire?

Comment: I'm not sure that this isn't a Linux/unix question if you'd accept an answer of "encrypt the payload first". I think you also have some underlying assumptions that you aren't exposing. What about SFTP? How slow is SCP? Do you mean on the local network? What security aspects of scp are attractive to you?

Comment: Are these files that need to be transferred/updated frequently? If so, you might try using rsync over ssh.

Comment: Even if you send encrypted tarballs you have to be concerned about the service's password passing over the wire unencrypted as in the case of faster FTP.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Unix&Linux.se.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`scp` uses the SSH protocol which is already up to the task to transferring at the full bandwidth allowed by the local network, at least on 100baseT ethernet. For gigabit networks, you may have to fiddle a bit, but usually the CPU is not the bottleneck.

Since you do not tell much details about your performance issues, I can only hazard hypotheses. What must be said is the following:

- Your network (the wires and network interfaces) have a maximum bandwidth. For instance, 100baseT ethernet runs at 100 Mbits/s (*bits*, not bytes), and there is a bit of overhead, so with such wires you may reach about 10 or 11 MBytes/s, no more. If `scp` on a single big file already gives you a comparable figure, then you are already as fast as you can go. If your performance is noticeably slower, then you should investigate hardware and driver issues.
- A normal, up-to-date `scp` installation should select a reasonably fast encryption algorithm (typically AES-128), that can be applied efficiently by even not-so-recent PC (100 MBytes/s would be typical). It is conceivable, through obsolete tools, misconfiguration, or anemic hardware from the previous century, that raw encryption speed is your problem. To test for that, you may want to run a CPU usage report tool (e.g. `top` on a Linux system) while you do the transfer, on both the client and server, to see if the CPU saturates. You may also want to run the `scp` command with the `-v` argument to get some details on the negotiated algorithm; look for something which looks like:

  `debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr umac-64-etm@openssh.com none`

  If you do not saturate on CPU, then you have no improvement to expect from a protocol change.
- **Compression** may or may not help. `scp` can compress data on the fly; use the `-C` flag to enable it. Compression can make some data shorter, hence allow it to be transferred faster, but this comes at a cost in CPU, which may then become the bottleneck. Big video, mp3 files and jpg pictures are already compressed and usually don't benefit from extra compression by `scp`.
- A known issue with `scp` is *latency*, not when transferring a single file, but when sending many small files: `scp` tends to wait for an acknowledge of reception of each file from the peer before proceeding with the next one.

  If that is your case, then solution is indeed to use another transfer protocol, but still within a SSH tunnel. You can, indeed, pipe some `tar` output; it is as simple as:

  `tar cf - somefiles | ssh theserver 'tar xf -'`

  However, you may find [rsync](https://rsync.samba.org/) easier to use. It can invoke `ssh` for you, so you still use the SSH tunnel (and thus benefit from all the security goodness), but it will be efficient for sending files, including optional compression and "syncing" directories (i.e. avoiding the sending of files which are already on the other side).